# Does it always hold that $n-\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(I_n-BA)-\operatorname{rank}(A(I_n-BA))$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $A,B \in \mathcal{M_{n}}(\mathbb{C})$. Does it always hold that $$n-\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(I_n-BA)-\operatorname{rank}(A(I_n-BA))\ ?$$

Attempt: Begin by noticing that $$\ker(A)\subseteq\operatorname{Im}(I_n-BA)$$ so $$n-\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq \operatorname{rank}(I_n-BA).$$

Also we know $$\mathrm{Im}(A(I_n-BA)) \subseteq \operatorname{Im}(I_n-BA)$$ and $$\operatorname{Im}(A(I_n-BA)) \subseteq \operatorname{Im}(A)$$ which implies $$\operatorname{rank}(A(I_n-BA)) \leq \operatorname{rank}(I_n-BA)$$ and $$\operatorname{rank}(A(I_n-BA)) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A)$$ respectively.

Comment: As a hint: do you know how to prove Sylvester's inequality? This one is similar to that.

Comment: @Q.Zhang yes, I forgot to upload the post, it's the equality case in Sylvester's inequality

Comment: See also this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4438910/337368 It was indeed one of our midterm exam problem. It also gives a proof of the problem you asked in a different post. Yes, it is true that $\mathrm{rank}(I-AB)=\mathrm{rank}(I-BA)$. Actually, for any $c\ne 0$, you can show that $rank(cI-AB)=rank(cI-BA)$.

Comment: @Q.Zhang Yes, thank you very much for your time! Both these were needed to solve a bigger problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dimension theorem (rank + nullity =n), it suffices to show that
$$\dim \ker(A-ABA)=\dim\ker(A)+\dim \ker(I-BA).$$
Note that $\ker(I-BA)\subset \ker(A-ABA)$, we can consider the map
$$T: \ker(A-ABA)/\ker(I-BA)\to \ker(A)$$
defined by
$$T(\bar x)=(I-BA)x,$$
where $\bar x=x+\ker(I-BA)$. This map is clearly well-defined and injective. It suffices to show it is surjective. But it is easy. For $y\in \ker(A)$, note that $T(\bar y)=(I-BA)y=y$, and thus $y\in \mathrm{Im}(T)$. This shows that it is surjective. We are done.

Comment: An interesting question is whether the set $ker(A−ABA)/ker(I−BA)$ is non empty, since proving it's non empty traces back to proving strict subset relation in the hypothesis, namely that $ker(A) \subset Im(I−BA)$. Do you have anything in mind? I suspect there must be a choice of $A, B$ such that this holds

Comment: @Summand It is new to me a quotient space can be empty. For a vector space $V$ and a subspace $W$, I think the quotient $V/W$ is never empty.

Comment: indeed it cannot be empty and there is a very simple example, as can be seen here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140855/is-the-quotient-space-xv-v-or-the-emptyset 
Again thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalent condition for the equality in Sylvester rank inequality (there is no need to prove it on each occasion):

> Let $X$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, and $Y$ an $n\times p$ matrix. Then $$\mathrm{rank}(XY)=\mathrm{rank}(X)+\mathrm{rank}(Y)-n \iff \ker (X)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(Y).$$

Now set $X=A$ and $Y=I_n-BA$.